# Does a unique collection give 4 or 7 points?

Tags: gloria-picktoria

In Gloria Picktoria, does a unique collection give 4 points because it is unique, or does it give 7 points because it is unique (4) but also the longest collection of that type in the game (3)?
Logically I would say that it gives just 4 points, but my rulebook is not clear on this point. What is the correct rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It only gives 4 points for being unique.** Unfortunately, the [English version](http://www.zoch-verlag.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Spielregeln/Huehnerregeln/GloriaPicktoria/SR-GloriaPicktoria-en.pdf) of the rules dropped the nice scoring example in the [German version](http://www.zoch-verlag.com/fileadmin/user_upload/Spielregeln/Huehnerregeln/GloriaPicktoria/SR-Gloria-dt.pdf) of the rules.

> **Ronja: 8 Punkte** - Niemand außer Ronja besitzt Masken. Das bringt ihr 4 Punkte ein. Bei den Statuen geht sie - wie Max - leer aus. Auch bei den Zahnketten bekommt sie keine Punkte, denn Max und Lea besitzen mehr davon. 4 Punkte bringt Ronja ihre konkurrenzlose Hutsammlung.

Roughly, this translates to. Ronja 8 points. No one but Ronja owns Masks. That brings her 4 points. As with Max, the statues score her nothing. Also, for the necklaces she scores no points, because Max and Lea have more of them. 4 points for Ronja's unrivaled collection of hats.

It is clear from the images in the rulebook, that Ronja is the only player with Dark Green Mask cards, and Yellow Hat cards. Since she only scored 4 + 4 = 8 for her two unique collections, you don't score those sets for longest of that type as well.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, since I asked the question we have been playing with the unique collections giving just 4 points instead of 7 as we did initially, but it's nice to see that someone took the time and effort to find the reason behind my confusion. I play the Dutch version of the game and it appears that (like the English one) it's also lacking the clear example that would have prevented the confusion. Thanks again for your answer.